How do I compare a binary nominal variable and a discrete variable?
I am trying to compare whether a service was delivered (yes/no) to how many outlier tasks staff had to complete (1, 2,... n).
What statistical test could I use for this?
Thank you.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that you want to compare them? Do you want to know, for instance, if more outlier tasks is associated with a lower probability of the service being delivered?

I'm not sure in what sense one would compare these. I could imagine seeing if/how they were related, but that's not an act of comparison as such.

There are a couple possibilities but I think logistic regression seems most apropos, as it seems that the number of tasks is an independent variable and whether service was delivered is a dependent variable. For dichotomous dependent variables, logistic regression is the default.

I will assume that you are not so much interested in a single instance of service being delivered or not, but in the count (number of times) the service was delivered, as a function of the "extra tasks". So you have a binomial count as your discrete D.V., and the [1 - n] possible number of tasks, as your discrete I.V. A simple linear regression (good old OLS) should tell you whether there is a correlation of not.
I would definitively at a minimum plot that scatter plot, to look at the data, and see if there is any apparent relationship. This is in fact my "First Rule of Statistics"; always first look at the data. What Joe Berkson, a statistician at the Mayo Clinic, called the IOTT: Inter Occular Traumatic Test: Plot the data and see if it hits you between the eyes. Which has as a corollary (with full credit to xkcd): Always try to get data that is so good that you do not need to do any statistics on it.
An advantage of this approach (beyond its simplicity) is that, if your data is sparse (i.e. for several values of the "extra tasks" I.V, you have few samples; then you can bin together several values of the I.V. (e.g. 0, less than 2, less than 4, 5 or more. Etc...), as needed, based on your data (if you have many instances at each value of the I.V., then you would not need to do this binning).
Another approach would be to again look at the binomial counts, for each of the $n$ "extra tasks, and set this up as a 2xn contingency matrix. Then any test of association (Fisher, $\chi^2$, and all their variations), could tell you if, the proportions for different number of "extra tasks" are similar, or not.
You could also run a series of 2x2 contingency matrix comparisons (possibly with multiple comparison correction (MCC), e.g. Sidak); I would actually do this as a preliminary step, to find the "best" possible bins for clustering the data. It may be that between 0 and 1 extra tasks, there is no significant difference, but there is for 2; or only for 3. Etc (e.g. no difference between 5 and 6, but some for 7). This would give me in a way an "optimal" binning for finding a correlation.
